# How should I assign a letter at random to another?

Tags: encryption, permutation

For my first ever project in Python, I wanted to code a cipher to encrypt simple messages ( no spaces or lower case to avoid that extra hassle for now ).

My idea was to either:

1. Choose a letter of the alphabet at random to assign to a letter of the message using lists ( without duplicates ) or
2. Shuffle the alphabet and assign a new letter using its position ( if a = 0 and b = 1 and so forth, the letter that took those position would be assigned to the letters of the message )

I managed to get a list of the letters of the alphabet using `list.ascii_lowercase` and a list of the letters in the message that needs to be encrypted but I'm not sure where to go from there. The second option is more appealing to me, but I don't know how to tackle the problem.

I hope I was clear enough, I'm very new to all of this. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: It's nice to see people getting enthusiastic with technologies, but nonetheless, this is a slightly bit off-topic here. What you're trying to achieve is known as "deterministic permutation of an alphabet", and probably based on a seed that's used as a key.

Comment: So, if you are looking for algorithmic help I think this question _could_ be on-topic for us (i.e. you don't insist on us helping you with concrete python code). If you are looking for implementation help (i.e. how to do simple thing `X` in python) then _look_ on [so] first. As it is I _think_ this question would be too broad for [so].

Comment: I'd use the shuffling method yourself. The shuffled alphabet is then your key. After that you can simply iterate over the message and grow your ciphertext by replacing one character by the character mapped to the same position. The so called permutation from alphabet to shuffled alphabet can be done by indexing or by mapping (0 -> 'C' or 'A' -> 'C').

Answer (score 0):

The programming part would be off-topic here, and I believe as an enthusiastic practitioner, you can figure it on your own.

Here's an idea for creating an alphabet map:

1. Initialization,

1.1. set `n` to the number of letters in the alphabet,

1.2. set `Permute` to an empty associative array (known as `dict` in python),

1.3. set `Alphabet` to the list of letters,

2. Seeding the permutation.

2.1. hash `chr(n)+seed` and obtain the result as an integer `v`,

2.2. calculate `v%n`, assign that to `u`.

2.3. remove `Alphabet[u]` from the list, assign it to `x`,

2.4. assign `x` to the key `chr(n)` of `Permute`,

2.5. Decrease `n` by 1, and if it's non-zero, repeat step 2.

3. Output `Permute` as the codebook.

Note that the `chr` in the illustrated steps takes the letter index instead of ASCII code, which you may need to do a bit of extra coding to take care of that.

Comment: `Permute = random.shuffle(Alphabet)` ;)